# Setting a certain default value on form upon clicking a specific hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a html page with multiple hyperlinks & another page consisting of a form. I would like to re-use the form by changing the default value, upon clicking a specific hyperlink.

For e.g, on page 1

```
<a href="..">Event 1</a> goes to the form that sets default option value to Event 1.
<a href="..">Event 2</a> goes to the form that sets default option value to Event 2.
& so on..
```

on form page, default values are selected upon clicking hyperlink on previous page.

```
<select>
   <option value = "1">Event 1</option>
   <option value = "2">Event 2</option>
   <option value = "3">Event 3</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way to do it with javascript? I can explore other options as well :)

Comment: Perhaps you could have the form on the same page? It would initially be hidden. Then, it would be displayed when the user clicks on one of the links.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jquery, this can be easily done. On the page with the form, do this.

On the page where you have the links like this:

```
<a href="myPage.html#event!">Event 1</a> goes to the form that sets default option value to Event 2
<a href="myPage.html#event2">Event 2</a> goes to the form that sets default option value to Event 1
```

where myPage is the page with the form, and then on 'myPage' do this:

```
$(function(){
  var link = document.URL;
  if(link == "myPage.html#event!"){
      $("select option").each(function(){
         if($(this).val() == 1){
              $(this).prop("selected", true);
              return;
           }
      });
  }
  else if(link == "myPage.html#event2"){
     // And so on..
   }
});
```

PS. If you have never used jquery before then you'll have to add this in your document:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code makes sense! Thanks so far.. but how do i specify the firstlink, secondlink as hyperlinks on the previous page?

Comment: @ZachShibuya Try having #values. So href for Event 1 will be '/linkToFormPage#form1' and so on. Then check for these links. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi sry for not updating, I manage to get it to work on the same page, , but somehow linking it from a page to the form page wont work. mind giving some examples?

Comment: @ZachShibuya I've updated my answer to the simplest possible form. Hope this helps.